# R:Non-standard reordering of the columns in data frame

Tags: r

i would like to reorder the columns in my data frame. It is not as simple as i thought so, first of all my data table is implemented in shiny app, where **number of columns differ**, it consist of 3 constant columns (`ID,Nr,Abm`) and the rest is reactive --> here starts the problem....

After whole data manipulations etc, my end product looks like this:

```
data <- structure(list(ID = structure(1L, .Label = "1", class = "factor"), 
  T800_600 = 547.21, T800_650 = 297.42, T800_700 = 109.38, 
  T800_750 = 39.99, Abkuehlrate_T800_600 = 0.37, Abkuehlrate_T800_650 = 0.5, 
  Abkuehlrate_T800_700 = 0.91, Abkuehlrate_T800_750 = 1.25, 
  Nr = 12, Abm = 20), .Names = c("ID", "T800_600", "T800_650", 
  "T800_700", "T800_750", "Abkuehlrate_T800_600", "Abkuehlrate_T800_650", 
  "Abkuehlrate_T800_700", "Abkuehlrate_T800_750", "Nr", "Abm"), 
  row.names = "1", class = "data.frame", na.action = structure(2L, 
    .Names = "NA", class = "omit"))
```

Output

```
  ID T800_600 T800_650 T800_700 T800_750 Abkuehlrate_T800_600 Abkuehlrate_T800_650
1  1   547.21   297.42   109.38    39.99                 0.37                  0.5
  Abkuehlrate_T800_700 Abkuehlrate_T800_750 Nr Abm
1                 0.91                 1.25 12  20
```

As we can see the order of columns is really messy. What i would like to get is at the beginning constant columns: `ID,Nr,Abm` and then sort of "descending order of columns": `ID`,`Nr`,`Abm`,`T800_750`,`T800_700`,`T800_650`,`T800_600`,`Abkuehlrate_T800_750`,`Abkuehlrate_T800_700`,`Abkuehlrate_T800_650`,`Abkuehlrate_T800_600`

**The data frame --> number of columns differ!, therefore manual typing cannot be considered.**

Thanks for ideas

Comment: How are the rest of the columns sorted? The example you give is not alphanumeric.

Comment: Just added an edit, with all the columns "sorted" the way they should be, the key to it is getting ascending order of `..800_750..`,`..800_700..`,`..800_650..`,`..800_600..`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
library(gtools)
data <- data[,mixedorder(colnames(data),decreasing = T)]
gr1 <- which(colnames(data) %in% c("ID","Nr","Abm"))
gr2 <- which(!colnames(data) %in% c("ID","Nr","Abm"))
data[c(gr1, gr2)]
  Nr ID Abm T800_750 T800_700 T800_650 T800_600 Abkuehlrate_T800_750 Abkuehlrate_T800_700 Abkuehlrate_T800_650
1 12  1  20    39.99   109.38   297.42   547.21                 1.25                 0.91                  0.5
  Abkuehlrate_T800_600
1                 0.37
```

The `gtools` package includes a `mixedorder()` function, which is pretty helpful here.